# Porque o método index() não reconhece o redirecionamento [CI]?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, route

Estou acompanhando um curso e parei em um problema que não consigo resolver. Neste [**link**](http://cii.mvnp.com.br/usuario/cadastro) é possível cadastrar um usuário e ao terminar o cadastro ele deveria ir para esta [**página**](http://cii.mvnp.com.br/usuario/1) mas a única coisa que acontece é um erro 404.

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard';
$route['usuario/{:num}'] = "usuario/index/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**Usuario.php**

> ***TÁ INSERINDO NO BANCO***

```
public function cadastrar()
{
    $data['nome']       = $this->input->post('nome');
    ...

    if( $this->db->insert('usuario', $data) ){
        redirect('usuario/1');
    } else {
        redirect('usuario/2');
    }

}
```

> ***NÃO ESTÁ REDIRECIONANDO***

```
public function index($indice=null)
{
    $this->load->view('includes/html_header');
    $this->load->view('includes/menu');
    if($indice==1){
        $data['msg'] = "Usuário foi cadastrado com sucesso";
        $this->load->view("includes/msg_sucesso", $data);
    } elseif ($indice==2) {
        $data['msg'] = "Não foi possível cadastrar o usuário. Tente novamente.";
        $this->load->view("includes/msg_erro", $data);
    }
    $this->load->view('listar_usuario');
    $this->load->view('includes/html_footer');

}
```

Os includes também estão corretos e por mais que não estivessem, acho que redireciona da mesma forma. Porque será não está redirecionando, está enviando [**essa página**](http://cii.mvnp.com.br/usuario/1) pro 404?

Answer (score 1):

Verifica no arquivo config/config.php se o valor da chave base_url do vetor $config está definido corretamente de acordo com a url do seu site/sistema:

```
//Site local
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';

//Servidor remoto
$config['base_url'] = 'http://meusite.com.br/';
```

A função **redirect** do CI utiliza o valor configurado na $config['base_url'] para gerar a url para onde será redirecionado o sistema e caso ela esteja configurada de forma errada o sistema será redirecionado para uma página não existe e assim retornando o erro 404(Página não encontrada).